# why inductor come first in low pass filter and resistor come first in high pass filter in RL filters?

Tags: filter, low-pass, physics, passive-filter, high-pass-filter

why inductor come first in low pass filter and resistor come first in high pass filter in RL filters ?

any link or sources

please explain in detail
[image]

[image]**strong text**

Comment: Because that's how the math works out.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams could you please explain why is it so ?

Comment: Do you understand poles and zero of these circuits?

Comment: nope but please explain this any reference or sources . i need that urgent tomorrow i have to submit the  assignment

Comment: WTF is your book smoking?  There's no reason that the shunt element has to be on a particular side of the series element...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, if the source impedance is 0, there is.

Comment: @ThePhoton -- ah.  nil source impedance isn't really a case that comes up much :P (my books didn't discuss that AFAICR)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, I don't remember what I first learned, but I can imagine filters like this first being defined with an ideal source driving them, and output being taken at the V_o node. Otherwise, how do you get a transfer function that doesn't depend on the source impedance?

Comment: This was a good question that was misunderstood by most of the commentors/answerers. What matters is not the order, but *which component we are measuring to generate the output voltage*. A filter is a frequency-dependent voltage divider. The order of resistors in a voltage divider doesn't matter, just which one you measure for the output signal. The way this circuit is drawn, going from Vin to ground, the last component is the one that is used for the output voltage, and in an RL lowpass the output voltage is across the resistor.

Comment: See this identical question for more details https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/269952/resistor-placement-in-filter-circuits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a DC signal (i.e. low frequency) hits a capacitor it is as if it is an open circuit. If an ac (high frequency) hits a capacitor it is as if it is a short circuit.

The opposite happens with an inductor.

Now, consider each circuit what happens with a high or low frequency signal. Short circuit if it is:

high frequency and capacitor
Low frequency and Inductor

open circuit if:
high frequency and inductor
low frequency and capacitor.

It is quite clear when doing this why each circuit acts the way it does.

Comment: So probably you are trying to say that 

at low frequency inductor act as a short circuit 
at high frequency inductor act as open circuit !! 

Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Inductors resist change in voltage.

Comment: i want to thank you but this site say it is prohibited :D

Comment: Done :) keep helping ! respect from Pakistan

Answer (score 1):

Low pass filters with one type energy storage element have to have a zero at infinity, that is high frequencies.  Putting the inductor before the resistor in the low pass provides this zero because it blocks high frequencies.  High pass filters with one type energy storage element have have to have a zero at zero frequency, that is a at DC.  Putting the inductor after the resistor provides this zero since the inductor is a short at DC.