# Resistor placement in filter circuits

Tags: ac, filter, low-pass, high-pass-filter

Why does the placement of the resistor in a filter circuit matter? I've heard if you switch an inductor and a resistor in a series circuit it could change the type of filter you get. Ex: From a low pass filter to a high pass filter.

Comment: If you put the gearbox backwards in a car what would you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things in nature simply aren't commutative.  A R-L filter is one of them.

In this case, the signal must pass thru one of the components, then the result is shunted to ground by the other.  It should be obvious that if you make the signal pass thru a high resistance then shunt the result to ground with a low resistance, you don't get much.  Conversely, if the signal passes thru a low resistance then is shunted to ground thru a high resistance, it will be largely unaffected.

In this case, you can think of the inductor as a frequency-variable resistor.  That's not exactly what it is, but it's a good enough mental model to understand low pass and high pass L-R filters at this level for now.

The effective resistance of the inductor goes up with frequency.  If it is in series, it will cause high frequencies to be attenuated more.  If it is the shunt, then it will affect high frequencies less.

Low pass filter:

[image]

High pass filter:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: My answer regards to RC filters but is equally applicable to RL filters

It's all a matter of what you consider as output, is the output voltage the voltage across the capacitor or across the resistor? your choice defines what is the filter. look on the image below for a visual illustration.

[image: RC lowpass VS RC highpass]

the order by which you place the resistor or capacitor will not change the voltage across them, but please note that when you wire an actual circuit if the input is ground referenced and you measure with a scope probe which has a ground clip you need to connect both grounds to the same spot and so you'll want to put the component you wish to see the voltage across last.

Answer (score 0):

The below will make more sense if you are familiar with Laplace transforms.

You may be aware that if you scale impedances in a voltage divider the output will be unchanged (assuming no loading and zero source impedance).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxkkaO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the above example, the right hand impedances have been multiplied by 10. The output response for any input will be the same for both circuits.

---

The same thing is also true if you scale the impedances by the Laplace variable s.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fry2Tf.png)</sup>

In the above example, the right hand impedances have been multiplied by (1K/1mH)/s. That **changes the 1mH inductor into a 1K resistor**, but the resistor changes into a 1nF **capacitor**, **not an inductor**. Both circuits will have the same response for any input, just as in the first example.

---

Note that the input and output impedances are different for the transformed circuits, and in the case of the RL circuits they change with frequency in different ways.